# android - closing a fragment on a complicated project

Tags: android, android-fragments

In the app I have my MainActivity and about 20 fragments that cycles inide it
i also have a menu fragment attached to a different container

So , 2 containers , one main menu fragment that slides from the left and about 20 fragments that keeps the other container very busy.

My questions is , how can I close the main menu fragment in this case "hide" using fragment manager when I click outside the main menu fragment.

Meaning , I just added the main menu layout an on click event that when pressed if the main menu fragment is on it will auto hide it , so far so good.. but not really , cause the main menu have a lot of different fragments inside it so when I click I actually clicking the layouts of the fragments which mean that the main activity layout on click event dose not happens.

any ideas?
Is there a way to click somewhere on the screen and record that click ? without the use of views clicks so maybe i can find the space where the main menu is not showing clicking and walla it will close right away..
maybe i should increase the size of the main menu using padding instead of margin then when i click it will click on the main menu fragment just not where it say stuffs (buttons) then the onclick will be recorded and it will be done .

any ideas or thoughts?
thank you for your time.

Comment: maybe adding some code of yours would help us see how you are doing and how we can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your post. I understand that you are going to implement a Home page with a navigation menu. When clicking menu items the content inside the main container changes.

Did you use NavigationDrawer or NavigationView to achieve this?  These components have the default behavior of closing menu when touches outside the menu (Your requirement).

Please visit this link to get an Idea about NavigationView - http://www.technotalkative.com/part-4-playing-with-navigationview/,
Or there is plenty of tutorials available on the web.

Comment: thank you saved as bookmark and will start exploring it soon.